# PHP PDO using bindParam selectivley

Tags: php, pdo

```
$pdo = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO agents (Agent_ID,Agent_Name,Agent_Branch) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$pdo->bindParam(1, $id);
$pdo->bindParam(2, $name);
$pdo->bindParam(3, $branch);
$pdo->execute();
```

So in this example I only need to really use bindParam on $branch because $name and $id have passed through a strict REGEX using preg_replace.

Is there a way to include these sanitised variables in the statement or any other way to shorten this code?

Comment: If you want it to look cleaner, why not use `$pdo->execute(array($id,$name,$branch));` instead?

Comment: When using `?` marks then do not use `bindParam()`. Pass a numeric array into execute with the same amount of elements as your query contains question marks.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat As I understand it bindParam will sanitise the data or have I got that wrong?

Comment: @user1209203: When you use prepared statements, the SQL query and the values are sent to the database separately. SQL injection only exists because people were building SQL query strings via string concatenation. Once you stop using `bindParam` and start concatenating variables into the string is when you re-enable the threat of SQL injection. There isn't any sanitization here because it's not needed. Using prepared statements/`bindParam` will protect you against SQL injection because of how it sends the values. You don't need to try to escape/sanitize your values if you are using this method.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat The point is they have been sanitised for other reasons therefore do not need to be sanitised a second time, $id will only be an integer and will be sanitised to ensure that for PHP and it's inclusion in the database, why then sanitise it again. What I would like to do is use bindParam when necessary, otherwise I have to use bindParam for every value if only one value actually needed it.

Comment: @user1209203: `bindParam` doesn't do any sanitization.  Prepared statements just have the values sent separately from the SQL so that sanitization isn't needed.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat  Ok I see that were the confusion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short way would be:

```
$pdo = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO agents (Agent_ID,Agent_Name,Agent_Branch) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$pdo->execute(array($id,$name,$branch));
```

if you ever wanted to bind parameters, replace the question marks with placeholders:

```
$pdo = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO agents (Agent_ID,Agent_Name,Agent_Branch) VALUES (:id,:name,:branch)");
$pdo->bindParam(':id', $id);
$pdo->bindParam(':name', $name);
$pdo->bindParam(':branch', $branch);
$pdo->execute();
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses his question. How would you go about updating only branch for instance?

Comment: @kba: I think this does answer the question.  He's not asking about only updating one variable.

Comment: Yes he does. He literally write: "I _only need_ to really use bindParam on $branch".

Comment: @kba But I still want to use bindParam to sanitise that variable, using execute(array.... doesn't do that does it? –

Comment: @user1209203 when you call prepare it will sanitize, that is the whole point of PDO

Comment: Ok sorry I'm new to PDO, I thought for some reason bindParam did something more useful.